# Reading Arabic Attachments using JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've a problem of downloading arabic attachment files using java mail.

The file name is always ambiguous.

The problem is the `Bodypart` retrieves the attachment as non-UTF-8 characters.

```
private void getAttachments(Message temp) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    List<File> attachments = new ArrayList<File>();

    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) temp.getContent();

    System.out.println(multipart.getCount());

    for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
        BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
        if (!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition())) {
            continue; // dealing with attachments only
        }
        InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();

        // getFilename always have wrong characters set 
        byte [] fileBytes = bodyPart.getFileName().toString().getBytes();

        String filename = new String(fileBytes, "UTF-8");            

        File f = new File("C:\\Attachments\\" + filename);

         System.out.println(f .getName());

         try {
        if (f == null) {
            //filename = File.createTempFile("VSX", ".out").getName();
            return;
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f );
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        int aByte;
        while ((aByte = bis.read()) >=0) {
            bos.write(aByte);
        }

        fos.flush();
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        bis.close();
        fos.close();
    } // end of try()
    catch (IOException exp) {
        System.out.println("IOException:" + exp);
    }        

        attachments.add(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way is `getFilename()` giving “wrong” characters?

Comment: @Donal Fellows: 
Filename is احمد صالح.doc 
After calling string filename = bodyPart.getFileName(); 
filename = "=?WINDOWS-1256?B?483jzyDU5M/sLmRvYw==?="

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The header is encoded according to the mechanism described in RFC 2047 (it's the `encoded-word`) which says that a section of a header matching `=?`*<encoding>*`?B?`*<encoded-bytes>*`?=` is a byte-encoded section. The *<encoding>* says how to interpret the bytes, and (because it's the `B` style, not the `Q` style) the *<encoded-bytes>* are base-64 encoded.

This is all rather complex. Luckily, you can deal with this easily by using the static `javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.decodeText()` method. That means you can switch to this:

```
String filename = MimeUtility.decodeText(bodyPart.getFileName());
```

Actually, you're better off combining that with the next line too as well:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Attachments",
                  MimeUtility.decodeText(bodyPart.getFileName()));
```

It's better because it avoids more trouble with building filenames than trying to do it all by hand. (It also means that you can factor out that literal pathname into some configuration location.)

Answer (score 3):

This part seems broken to me:

```
byte[] fileBytes = bodyPart.getFileName().toString().getBytes();
String filename = new String(fileBytes, "UTF-8");
```

You're using the default platform encoding to *encode* the filename (which you'd already got as a string) as bytes, and then *decoding* them using UTF-8.

What's wrong with:

```
String filename = bodyPart.getFileName();
```

? Don't do any more encoding and decoding than you need. Of course, whether your file system can handle such a filename is a different matter, but at least you're not losing data at this point any more...

(Your method of copying the file *data* is also nastily inefficient and will leave open streams in the case of exceptions. You might want to look at [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) to write easy code which gets this write...)

Comment: Filename is احمد صالح.doc
After calling 
string filename = bodyPart.getFileName();

filename = "=?WINDOWS-1256?B?483jzyDU5M/sLmRvYw==?="

Comment: @AhmedSaleh: Okay, so you need something which will decode that. Calling `toString()` and `getBytes` isn't going to help you there. Have a look for quoted printable classes - that's basically what you've got here. Your JVM will need to know the Windows-1256 code page to decode it successfully though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but kindly tell me what are printable classes ?

Comment: @AhmedSaleh: Sorry, "quoted printable" is the name of the sort of wrapper encoding used here. You'll need to search for an appropriate quoted printable helper class - either in javamail or a separate library.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
String decoded = MimeUtility.decodeText(part.getFileName()); 
return Normalizer.normalize(decoded, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
```