# Read mime file name using Java API

Tags: java, mime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading Arabic Attachments using JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783066/reading-arabic-attachments-using-javamail)

I have the code to extract the file name, body, subject from a mime message using Java API. But if the file name is in chinese characters, the code reads it as some encoded value

```
for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {

    BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);  
    **String fileName   = bodyPart.getFileName();
}
```

Where do I set any type of character set so that it will be read accurately?

Comment: The "duplicate" talks about Arabic rather than Chinese but the principle is the same, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7784066/592139) in particular will be useful.

Comment: Thank you ian. This is exactly what i was looking for. Should have go through a few countries before posting :)